# Is it more optimal to cleanse data with regex in SSIS rather than SQL queries?

Tags: regex, ssis

I am trying to cleanse a field in SQL server using regex replace CLR funcions. However, the query is taking forever to run. I am wondering if doing the same logic using a script component in SSIS would be any faster.

Answer (score 1):

I've never met a DBA who let me load Assemblies onto a Prod Server!
But I've certainly found that String manipulation via SSIS Script Component was much faster than using CHARINDEX & SUBSTRING etc via SQL.

SSIS can execute the compiled .net code so that it can run all records in a buffer through the script task in parallel provided the code is non-blocking. Try and fit as many rows as possible into your buffer by minimizing the "width" (toal col size) of your data flow.
This might mean its faster to just take your fields to be cleansed & a primary key and bulk load these to a new empty table. You can always inner join this back to your original table afterwards...

So I'd be optimistic that SSIS Could perform adequately. 
I would certainly run a quick test as the c# regex code for your script component can pretty much be lifted and dropped directly from your existing clr.